# How to manage ASP.NET parameters and Javascript keys

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

So here is my scenario.

Im using ASP.NET MVC 3 along with HTML, CSS, JavaScript/JQuery to make a web application.
Im using Visual Studio 2010

We have already released the product (its in 1.0), however now that we are in "maintenance" mode for the project, I have a feeling that as the project has new features added, that it will be harder to maintain the set of constants between both the C# (ASP.NET MVC) and the JavaScript.

For example, in the JavaScript I would create a $.post and have it link to the MVC url Controller/Action and then I would pass in parameters { key1: value1, key2: value2}

The issue is that if the C# parameter names change or if the position of parameters in the signature change, I will only know at run-time that the JavaScript needs to be updated (im assuming that im a programmer that doesn't know the architecture well enough to do this before run time).

So my question is, how do you manage the JavaScript side more easily so that i can stay "in-sync" with changes made on the C# side.  Can the compiler do this for me in some way, or is there a plug-in that can help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: *change or if the position of parameters* does not have any effect. Sounds like you want to implement a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel design pattern? like http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: Yes and no, this is more for managing C# constants and Javascript constants in a synchronous way more or less, and managing the function calls made in JS

Comment: There is no easy way...

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks about syncing C# constants and JavaScript constants, but then also talks about parameter names and positions.

The positions of parameters matter less in the MVC world than the names, and I've not found a good way of keep those in sync short of extensive unit and integration testing. You are doing those tests, right? ;)

As far as actual constants and enums, I've taken to using T4 templates to generate both a .cs and a (namespaced) .js file for the constants/enums I need (in my case, out of a database, but could just as easily be anything else).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any easy way, but here is something that may help. when I usually develop some website , first of all I try to write as least possible javascript code in views and have them all in .js file, this way you can be sure that you can reuse many codes and since all codes are pure javascript there won't be any problem you mentioned. I also keep the record of all actions with their controller and area name in database and use them for manage permissions and security issues. for your problem you can add all this method to database and later with a piece of code check if this method exist anymore.

adding to DB:(in base controller, so you don't need to do anything manually )

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var area = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            string areaName = area != null ? area.ToString() : "";
            var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

           //Add to DB
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

check if that exist:

```
bool exist = false;
 try
 {
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");
      using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
           exist = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
      }
 }
 catch
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is integration tests. You'll be able to test exactly the actions your users would do. [Seleno](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.Seleno) is a good option (it wraps Selenium) for writing integration tests.

It's worth doing. If you have good integration test coverage you'll run into fewer bugs in production.